# Sum of timeStamp in Mysql

Tags: mysql

> I'm trying to get the average of Completed time, so at first, I'm getting the completed time of individual processOrders.

below Query will get the Completed time for Individual processOrders.

```
select processorder_prod_number,ifnull(time(round( timediff(max(completed_time), 
min(start_time)))) ,'00:00:00') as `completedtime`
from processorder_prod where week(start_time)=week(curdate())
group by processorder_prod_number;
```

Output is like this

```
+--------------------+----------------+
| processorder_number| completedtime  | 
+--------------------+----------------+
|   1002135897       |  01:42:15      |
|   1002135898       |  01:39:43      |
|   1002135900       |  05:31:52      |
|   1002135901       |  02:31:52      |
+--------------------+----------------+
```

when I tried to get the total time, i.e sum(completedtime), it's getting the wrong output.

```
select count(distinct processorder_prod_number),time(round(sum(completedtime))) as totaltime from
(select processorder_prod_number,ifnull(time(round( timediff(max(completed_time), 
min(start_time)))) ,'00:00:00') as `completedtime`
from processorder_prod where week(start_time)=week(curdate())
group by processorder_prod_number) as t;
```

Output from above query

```
+---------------------------+----------------+
| count(processorder_number)| completedtime  | 
+---------------------------+----------------+
|   4                       |   01:42:15     |
+---------------------------+----------------+
```

please help me where I'm doing wrong.Any suggestions and corrections welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry error resolved now. but still output is wrong.

Comment: Post your DDL please

Comment: are the order you show referred to this week, itis imposrtant sinc ein your query you have week(curdate())

Comment: yes, need to get data for only current week @RobertoBenazzato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, You will get Sum of Completed Time.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) AS `completedtime` FROM dual;
```

Updated Answer

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT processorder_prod_number), TIME(ROUND(SUM(completedtime))) AS  totaltime FROM (SELECT processorder_prod_number, IFNULL(SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `completed_time` ) ) ),'00:00:00') AS  `completedtime`  FROM processorder_prod WHERE WEEK(start_time)=WEEK(CURDATE())  GROUP BY processorder_prod_number) AS t;
```

Comment: can you please share complete Query @Aishwarya

Comment: I tried with updated answer, but Sum is not correct. Thanks for quick response @Aishwarya

Comment: Just try to include that function in your query because i am getting correct answer 09:45:59 @ullas sharma